# Не работают горячие клавиши в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Почему могут не работать горячие клавиши в IDEA?

Выделяю 3 строки, жму Ctrl + Shift + /
и строки не становятся закомментироваными. Справа от номера строки появлается цифра 7 в квадратике и всё...

В Settings -> Keymap стоит Default

Comment: а операционная система у вас какая стоит?

Comment: У меня лично перестает работать хот кеи после того, как я поменяю раскладку клавиатуры, то есть сменю язык.

Comment: @MoloF Вообще все или некоторые? Очень часто на русской раскладке не работают Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+Y. Проверил сейчас - в ИДЕА тоже не работают, хотя остальные хоткеи работают и на русской раскладке.

Comment: @Эникейщик , нет, только комментирование

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Так я решил свою проблему с горячими клавишами

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема на Linux, мне помогло после того как я в настройках клавиатуры поставил английскую раскладку перед русской[image: введите сюда описание изображения]